# Browser prompts to download php file rather than it being rendered

Tags: php, .htaccess, content-type

This morning I was making changes to my .htaccess file and inadvertently broke something on my site and for the life of me I can not figure out what I did. Now the browser prompts to download php file rather than it being rendered.

Prior to my changes the site was working properly. I tried reverting back to the original backup copies of the files and .htaccess and still I having the same problem.

The site I am having my problem with is http://asteroidsinc.com/

However when I visit from the /index.php URL it appears to be functioning correctly.

The headers are as follows:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: asteroidsinc.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __utma=79720583.1041020739.1336336641.1336336641.1336336641.1;      __utmb=79720583.3.10.1336336641; __utmc=79720583; __utmz=79720583.1336336641.1.1.utmcsr=    (direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __atuvc=2|19

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 May 2012 20:44:00 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 03 May 2012 10:32:07 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 13811
Age: 6521
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php
```

The last line there “Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php” is of particular concern as I am pretty sure it should be “text/html”.

the original .htaccess file follows (simply redirecting the www to the non www)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.asteroidsinc\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/asteroidsinc\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I have tried to add the following into my .htaccess file but with no success.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

But this does not solve the problem.

I also tried the following line

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

but I think that php is in fact properly being parsed as it works when try accesing it via the /index.php URL

As mentioned above, I am not sure exactly what I changed and have tried reverting back to the original copies and still the problem persists.

****EDIT
I am now wondering if the problem is some sort of caching issue as I completely deleted the index.php file that was being prompted for download and yet when I try to visit the domain URL it still prompts me to download the file even though It had been completely deleted off the web server (I know almost nothing about caching)

**EDIT AGAIN
Yet another interesting thing I noticed was when I append a random string to the end of my URL (i.e. http://asteroidsinc.com/?random=1923849839) it will load just fine.  Does this mean it is a caching issue?  Will it just go away when the cache is finally cleared?

Comment: Why not post the .htaccess file if you think that caused the problem

Comment: I do believe that php is still enabled as php works on other pages. For example: asteroidsinc.com/contact.php resolves correctly

Comment: The original .htaccess file was as added above